# Multi-column glossary style with descriptions wrapped inside their own column

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm trying to make a multicolumn glossary style (with `glossaries`) that can handle long descriptions, but I'm rather unfamiliar with how to write a glossary style, and don't exactly know how to pull it off.

What I'd like to have is a glossary with four columns; two pairs of abbreviation and description. If a description is more than one line, the description should only wrap within its own column, and the abbreviation column should skip however many lines to keep each abbreviation lined up with the start of its description.

All I know how to do is make two total columns and manually separate the abbreviation and the description; via this code (which I'm quite sure I copypasted off of StackExchange some while ago):

```
\newglossarystyle{glossabbr}{%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
{\begin{multicols}{2}\raggedright}
    {\end{multicols}}

\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
\renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{} 

% set how each entry should appear:
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
    \noindent\makebox[7em][l]{\glstarget{##1}{\textsc{\glossentryname{##1}}}}
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\\
}
\renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
    \glossentry{##2}{##3}
}
}
```

The problem with this code is that when you have a long description, it just wraps over into the abbreviations column, because LaTeX isn't treating the abbreviation and the description as separate blocks. You can see the problem here, highlighted in red:

[image: Glossary with bad word wrap]

Ultimately all I'd like to do is just take those wrapped description bits (the bits not in small caps) and shove them over, confining them in the column for descriptions and leaving whitespace in the abbreviations column where they are right now. How do I make that happen?

MWE with the problematic glossary style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym
{inform}{inform}{informative illocutionary force}
\newacronym
{point}{point}{demonstrative illocutionary force}

\usepackage{multicol}
\newglossarystyle{glossabbr}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{multicols}{2}\raggedright}
        {\end{multicols}}
    
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{} 
    
    % set how each entry should appear:
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
        \noindent\makebox[7em][l]{\glstarget{##1}{\textsc{\glossentryname{##1}}}}
        \glossentrydesc{##1}\\
    }
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
        \glossentry{##2}{##3}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\glsunsetall

\gls{point}

\gls{inform}

\printglossary[style=glossabbr]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The easiest might be using tabular glossary style wrapped in multicols environment ... Did you consider that? Otherwise, I tryed to force-switch columns to no avail.

Comment: @TomášKruliš That's a good idea! I don't know how to do that, exactly, though; though I suppose I could make a stab at it. Would you be able to describe how that works as an answer?

Comment: well, found out it doesnt work like that ... Maybe wrap everything in minipages.

Comment: @TomášKruliš Two minipages with a tabular style in each? How would I tell it where to column break?

Comment: My suggestion was about wrapping each description and each name into theyre own minipage. How to do that, I am not so sure ... Probably there will be macro in style definition like `\glsdescfmt` or something, that could be redefined ... Although I am trying to cut through the `glossaries` and friends docs and code definitions, it is very complex and for me very advanced. Mrs. Talbot is one heck of a TeX programmer ...

Comment: @TomášKruliš Oh my! That's certainly above my TeX level, then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a good start for a complete solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym
{inform}{inform}{informative illocutionary force}
\newacronym
{point}{point}{demonstrative illocutionary force}

\usepackage{multicol}
\newglossarystyle{glossabbr}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{multicols}{2}\raggedright}
        {\end{multicols}}
    
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{} 
    
    % set how each entry should appear:
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
        \noindent\makebox[7em][l]{\glstarget{##1}%
            {\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
                \textsc{\glossentryname{##1}}
            \end{minipage}
        }}
        \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
        \glossentrydesc{##1}
        \end{minipage}\\
    }
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
        \glossentry{##2}{##3}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\glsunsetall

\gls{point}

\gls{inform}

\printglossary[style=glossabbr]

\end{document}
```

Please note the added `minipage` environments around `glossentryname` and `glossentrydesc`. This is kind-of raw workaround.

You should try to tweak the environment to you needs - width could be increased (maybe, but this looks acceptable) and I am having trouble setting vertical alignment of glossary entry to top , not center.

I leave that up to your research ;)

Comment: This is good enough for my purposes, at least! Thank you!

Comment: Turns out the vertical alignment problem is solved by setting both `\minipage`s to `[t]`. After that the only problem is vertical spacing, which is easily solvable.

Comment: @Sjiveru Oh, OK, I have set only one ... That did not occured to me. I am glad that it works. Also, it happens that just an hour ago I have hit upon `cals` package, which claims to be able to allow usage of tables in multicols (which is what I was unable to do in the beginning). Havent tested though ...