# How to get acronyms entries in uppercase letters and capitalize only the first letter of the entries from the glossary?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, capitalization, styles, uppercase

I found a lot of information on this forum about how to present the entries into a glossary (uppercase, lowercase, first letter capitalized); but I don't understand how to have two different styles for the acronyms list and the glossary, and present the entries differently.
Here is the code I use to capitalize the first letter into the glossary; but this affects the acronym list and the glossary. It's OK for the glossary, but I want the acronym entries in uppercase for the whole words...

Here is a full MWE...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts,automake,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\usepackage{glossary-tree}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Capitalize the first letter of the entry %%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\capitalize}{>{\SplitList{~}}m}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_capitalize_words_seq
  \ProcessList{#1}{\CapitalizeFirst}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_capitalize_words_seq { ~ }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\CapitalizeFirst}{m}
 {
  \capitalize_word:n { #1 }
 }

\sys_if_engine_pdftex:TF
 {
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \capitalize_tl_set:Nn { protected@edef }
 }
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \capitalize_tl_set:Nn \tl_set:Nn
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \capitalize_word:n
 {
  \capitalize_tl_set:Nn \l_capitalize_word_tl { #1 }
  \seq_if_in:NfTF \g_capitalize_exceptions_seq { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }
   % exception word
   { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_capitalize_words_seq { #1 } } % exception word
   % to be uppercased
   { \seq_put_right:Nx \l_capitalize_words_seq { \tl_mixed_case:V \l_capitalize_word_tl } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_mixed_case:n { V }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AppendToList}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_capitalize_exceptions_seq { \tl_to_str:n { ##1 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_if_in:NnTF { Nf }
\seq_new:N \l_capitalize_words_seq
\seq_new:N \g_capitalize_exceptions_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\capitalize{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
        name=latex,
        description={Is a mark up language specially suited for 
scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
        name=mathematics,
        description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{formula}
{
        name=formula,
        description={A mathematical expression}
}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}


\begin{document}

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. \Glspl{formula} are 
rendered properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.

Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This 
process is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full MWE. From what you have written in question, I guess you are looking for commands `\setglossarystyle`, `\setacronymstyle` and such. If so, they are described in package docs. And thumbs up for using `ExplSyntax` ;)

Comment: Thanks ; I edited my previous message providing a full MWE.
\setacronymstyle{short-sc-long} doesn't work for me with \usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra} ?

Comment: Well, the part with `Expl3` definition is too complex for me, but you might look at this question: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562957/multi-column-glossary-style-with-descriptions-wrapped-inside-their-own-column/563714?noredirect=1#comment1421546_563714
where some else had similar requirement, but he just created new abbreviation (acronym) style. I think you could reuse most of the code there, and have different style for your main glossary. All the same you could translate that to `Expl3` if you like.

Comment: Thanks ! I get the answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution is when you call the acronyms: you have to modify you glsnamefond command like this: \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{#1} \printglossary[type=\acronymtype] It works now: acronyms are in uppercase, only the first letter is capitalized in the glossary.