# Capitalize first letter in list of acronyms using the acro package

Tags: capitalization, acro

How can I capitalize the first letter in the list of acronyms with the `acro` package without adjusting all acronym declarations? A solution that capitalizes all first letters of all words would also be acceptable.

**What I have tried**

`acro` allows setting individual formats for list entries.
However, `\MakeUppercase` affects all letters instead of only the first one (see MWE). `\capitalisewords` has not effect.

**MWE**

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
%\usepackage{mfirstuc}  % for \capitalisewords
\DeclareAcronym{PC}{short=PC,long=personal computer}

\begin{document}

I am writing this on my \ac{PC}.

%\acsetup{format/list={\capitalisewords}}  % has no effect
\acsetup{format/list={\MakeUppercase}}  % not working as expected
\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

With `\MakeUppercase`:

[image]

Without `\MakeUppercase`:

[image]

**Related questions do not apply**

I have found several related questions, but none seems to apply.

| Question |  |
| --- | --- |
| [Capitalize the first letter in acronym list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57975/capitalize-the-first-letter-in-acronym-list) | solutions are specific to `acronym` package, or require redefinition of all acronym declarations (which I would like to avoid) |
| [Capitalization of the first letter in acronym list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575381/capitalization-of-the-first-letter-in-acronym-list) | refers to [Capitalize the first letter in acronym list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57975/capitalize-the-first-letter-in-acronym-list) |
| [Capitalize first letter of each word when printing list of acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481302/capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-when-printing-list-of-acronyms) | solutions are specific to `glossaries` package or require redefinition of all acronym declarations |
| [capitalisation and list of acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334599/capitalisation-and-list-of-acronyms) | solutions are specific to `glossaries` package |
| [How to get acronyms entries in uppercase letters and capitalize only the first letter of the entries from the glossary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563582/how-to-get-acronyms-entries-in-uppercase-letters-and-capitalize-only-the-first-l) | specific to `glossaries` package |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like I haven't documented all options… :|

You have to set the option `uppercase/list`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  uppercase/list
}

\DeclareAcronym{PC}{short=PC,long=personal computer}

\begin{document}

I am writing this on my \ac{PC}.

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the first letter of each word capitalised, i.e., want to use `mfirstuc` then you have to set the option `list/uppercse/cmd` as well and use `\ecapitalisewords`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\acsetup{
  uppercase/list ,
  list/uppercase/cmd = \ecapitalisewords
}

\DeclareAcronym{PC}{short=PC,long=personal computer}

\begin{document}

I am writing this on my \ac{PC}.

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]